# Data augmentation via permutation of the inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator

My model takes as input 4 arrays and is trained using the standard keras fit function in the following way:

```
model.fit([train[0],train[1],train[2],train[3]], train_labels)
```

These 4 arrays have the same dimension and they are in fact interchangeable.
The dictionary 'train' is loaded into RAM.
To overcome heavy overfitting and improve the performance of the model, I would like to enhance the dataset 24 times, being 24 the number of all the possible permutations of [1,2,3,4].
Moreover, I'd like to do it in a space-efficient way: not writing it to disk and then loading it while training the model.
I can **not** use itertools.permutations on the dataset as I can't afford having a dataset 24 times as big as the starting one in RAM.
Is there a way to do this using some sort of custom data generator?

Comment: `itertools.permutations`?

Comment: I'm aware of it, the problem if that I can't afford to have a dataset 24 times bigger in RAM. Also added this info in the question for clarity

Comment: I believe `itertools.permutations` is just a regular python generator, so it won't attempt to copy the data - as long as you avoid doing something that requires evaluating all permutations at once, like calling `list(itertools.permutations( ... ))`.

Comment: This is true, however you don't want to let the model see the whole 4 arrays, then permute them, then repeat the cycle etc. Instead you want to access to random permutations and indices. Surely, itertools.permutation needs to be called somewhere, but I assume wrapped in a custom gen first